# Flutter Web fails with firebase "Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found"

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

Since today I can not run my Flutter Web project anymore because it fails with:

> : Error: Too many positional arguments: 1 allowed, but 2 found.
> firebase_auth_web.dart:94
> Try removing the extra positional arguments.
> FirebaseCoreWeb.registerService('auth', (firebaseApp) async {
> ^
> : Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
> firebase_core_web.dart:43
> static void registerService(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I've already updated the `Core` and `Auth` to the latest versions:

> firebase_core: ^2.14.0
>
> firebase_auth: ^4.2.10

And I am running `Flutter 3.10.0`.

Anyone else experiencing this issue? I didn't change anything, at least not on purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same problem since June 10th, however it was not critical for me to solve. Just saw your post and tried it again.
Solved it by running:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub upgrade firebase_core_web
flutter pub upgrade firebase_auth_web
flutter pub upgrade
```

Maybe the packages have been updated and the version interference is not there anymore. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do a `flutter clean` and then a `flutter pub get` again, it seems like somehow you're getting an old version of `firebase_auth`.

Because in the newest version (which is the one that you've listed), the call to `registerService` doesn't look like that, it looks like [this](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth_web/lib/firebase_auth_web.dart#L94), i.e. one positional parameter and one named.

You can also see that is how the call should be looking like in [firebase_core](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_core/firebase_core_web/lib/src/firebase_core_web.dart#L43).

Also make sure that you don't have any dependency overrides.

Comment: tried it, but sam error...

Comment: Strange, if you add those dependencies to a completely new project, does the same happen?